# How to make a single producer queue push method to be multi producer?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a single producer queue and I'd like it to work with multiple threads. 
Queue is just a simple ring buffer queue. I have a pop method already implemented and it works for single producer - multi consumers. I am not sure what is wrong with my push method.

I tried to use CAS loop for write position, but it just pauses my program and does nothing.

```cpp
template<typename T, uint size = 1>
struct mpWriter
{
    bool push(const T& element)
    {
        while (true) {
            uint oldWritePosition = writePosition.load();
            uint newWritePosition = getPositionAfter(oldWritePosition);

            // if the write position is the old write position
            // advance the write position (so, now it is the new write position
            // and write data to the old write position 
            // if this makes sense
            if (writePosition.compare_exchange_strong(oldWritePosition, newWritePosition)) {
                ringBuffer[oldWritePosition].store(element);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    static constexpr uint getPositionAfter(uint position) noexcept
    {
        return ++position == ringBufferSize ? 0 : position;
    }

    static constexpr uint ringBufferSize = size + 1;
    std::atomic<T> ringBuffer[ringBufferSize];
    std::atomic<uint> writePosition = 0;
};
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    mpWriter<int, 50> ints;
    std::vector<std::thread> producers;

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        producers.push_back(std::thread([&](){
            ints.push(0);
        }));
    }

    for (auto& producer : producers) {
        producer.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with the code? How to write it properly? I do not want to use any external queues. I want to understand how it is done.

Comment: What do you mean it just pauses your program? Does it not terminate? I see no reason why it should not terminate - in fact I just tried it out and it terminates as expected. Regarding the logic of the queue as such: you should note that in case of a wrap-around, you could have producers overtake consumers, effectively overwriting items that have not yet been consumed!